# Oracle SQL%ROWCOUNT equivalent for DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there an equivalent of `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to run for `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` ?? Currently if i run `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after the statement it will only return 1.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks =)

Comment: you mean `SQL%ROWNUMS` or `SQL%ROWCOUNT`

Comment: yes my bad ... it's supposed to be SQL%ROWCOUNT

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question! I never realised that need. Maybe due to the fact that DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE is designed and used typically for DML operation on large tables (mn of rows) affecting a large portion of it.
Therefore, for me, it did not matter how much rows affected (`SQL$ROWCOUNT`) for each chunk.
I had my own validation scripts to verify in the end if task achieved its overall purpose.

> However, this can perhaps be introduced in future version of oracle.
>   As far as I am aware (upto 12c) none of DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE views gives this
>   additional info

Having said that, you can always write and call your custom procedure thru run_task. You can write `SQL$ROWCOUNT` in a log file or table after DML operation inside `MY_PROCEDURE`.

```
DECLARE
  l_task     VARCHAR2(30) := 'parallel_processing';
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_try      NUMBER;
  l_status   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => l_task);

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_rowid(task_name   => l_task,
                                               table_owner => 'SCHEMANAME',
                                               table_name  => 'T_PROCESS',
                                               by_row      => TRUE,
                                               chunk_size  => 10000);

  l_sql_stmt := 'begin MY_PROCEDURE( :start_id, :end_id ); end;';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => l_task,
                                 sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
                                 language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 10);

  -- If there is error, RESUME it for at most 2 times.
  l_try := 0;
  l_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task);
  WHILE(l_try < 2 and l_status != DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.FINISHED) 
  Loop
    l_try := l_try + 1;
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.resume_task(l_task);
    l_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task(l_task);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - basically what you'd be asking is what was the SQL%ROWCOUNT for each of the tasks that executed for the chunks you ran. None of the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE Subprograms seem to have any way of finding out how many records were updated in that chunk, and the DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS table doesn't have a count of rows in the chunk.

The best way I can think would be to put the SQL$ROWCOUNT into each task that you are executing, and have it write to a table and then sum that up at the end of the task, or to do a select count(*) once the task completes and count the rows that you updated (assuming you can tell from the update you did - if you set a processed flag or batch ID or something).